# Can't get haproxy to load balanace Galera Cluster nodes

Tags: redhat, haproxy, galera

I recently installed Galera Cluster on two Red Hat 7 servers and have it configured correctly. However I can't get HAProxy to work. I'm just getting errors.

Node 1 has an IP of 1.1.1.1 and all traffic is open. SELinux has mysql set to permissive.

Node 2 has an IP of 2.2.2.2 and all traffic is open. SELinux has mysql set to permissive.

HAProxy has an IP of 3.3.3.3 and all traffic is open. SELinux has been disabled.

All nodes are on separate servers. The only thing Node 3 has installed on it is HAProxy and mysql client.

So per the Galera documentation, I install HAProxy and add this portion to the bottom of the config file:

```
# Load Balancing for Galera Cluster
listen galera 3.3.3.3:3306
     balance roundrobin
     mode tcp
     option tcpka
     option mysql-check user haproxy
     server node1 1.1.1.1:3306 check weight 1
     server node2 2.2.2.2:3306 check weight 1
```

But then when I check status of HAProxy I get these errors:

```
[root@nodemgr haproxy]# service haproxy restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  haproxy.service
[root@nodemgr haproxy]# service haproxy status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  haproxy.service
● haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-07-04 20:18:50 EDT; 3s ago
  Process: 11773 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11773 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr systemd[1]: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.
Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr systemd[1]: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...
Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr haproxy-systemd-wrapper[11773]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /ru...pid -Ds
Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr haproxy-systemd-wrapper[11773]: [WARNING] 184/201850 (11774) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:45] : 'option httplog'...cplog'.
Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr haproxy-systemd-wrapper[11773]: [WARNING] 184/201850 (11774) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for proxy 'galera' ...P mode.
Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr haproxy-systemd-wrapper[11773]: [ALERT] 184/201850 (11774) : Starting proxy galera: cannot bind socket [3.3.3.3:3306]
Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr systemd[1]: haproxy.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr haproxy-systemd-wrapper[11773]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit, haproxy RC=1
Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr systemd[1]: Unit haproxy.service entered failed state.
Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr systemd[1]: haproxy.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I'm assuming my problem is here:

```
 Jul 04 20:18:50 nodemgr haproxy-systemd-wrapper[11773]: [ALERT] 184/201850 (11774) : Starting proxy galera: cannot bind socket [3.3.3.3:3306]
```

but after disabling SELinux I don't know what else I need to do. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Full haproxy config file is here:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  main *:5000
    acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
    acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js

    use_backend static          if url_static
    default_backend             app

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend static
    balance     roundrobin
    server      static 127.0.0.1:4331 check
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:5001 check
    server  app2 127.0.0.1:5002 check
    server  app3 127.0.0.1:5003 check
    server  app4 127.0.0.1:5004 check

# Load Balancing for Galera Cluster
listen galera 3.3.3.3:3306
     balance roundrobin
     mode tcp
     option tcpka
     option mysql-check user haproxy
     server node1 1.1.1.1:3306 check weight 1
     server node2 2.2.2.2:3306 check weight 1
```

Comment: `netstat -a -n | grep ':3306'`... anything showing? Does `ifconfig` show an actual interface with 3.3.3.3 bound to it?

Comment: After hours of scratching my head I found this step to work: vi /etc/sysctl.conf and add ‘net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1’ to bottom of file

Comment: That shouldn't have been necessary.  `listen galera :3306` would probably have accomplished what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

vi /etc/sysctl.conf and add ‘net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1’ to bottom of file ended up doing what I needed.